# Wireguard connected to multiple VPN peers

Tags: vpn, wireguard

I have a wireguard setup which connects my mobile devices with a wireguard instance running in a VPS.

This allows me to access both my internal resources, and the internet, as if I was on the VPS.

The problem I have is that many services see the address as a data centre anddress and I get increased CAPTCHA requests, or downright banned, from certain sites.

I want to connect my wireguard infrastructure to a third peer with an VPN provider and route all traffic across it.

How do I configure my wireguard host (middle of the diagram) to route all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 out through the VPN provider peer?

[image]

Comment: welcome, home and enduser question are offtopic on serverfault.com but might be on topic on superuser.com instead. aslong as you hide critical information from us, it is also offtopic, you may want to read carefully [ask] and update the question afterwards

Comment: Thanks djdomi. This actually is in a business context, not a home context. I have solved the problem using iptables to route all of the traffic out through the external VPN, being hosted on the corporate network. I’ll post the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update, please add an answer to the question else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem